# Can we describe 1 container in a pod using command like kubectl describe container

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is it possible to describe just 1 container in a pod?

```
$ kubectl describe pod <pod_name>
```

describes all the containers in that pod.

Thanks.

Comment: No, There is no such thing.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no a dedicated command to do that. But you can use `kubectl get pods` to show the info per container. For example with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) you can get info for a container by its name:

```
kubectl get pod <pod_name> -n <namespace_name> -o json | jq -c  '.spec.containers[] | select( .name | contains("<container_name>"))'
```

Comment: Thanks @Anna Slastnikova. This command doesn't give all the info that kubectl describe does. For example, it is showing if the container is Ready or not.

Comment: True, then just save output of `kubectl describe` into a file and analyze it. Also another quick way to check if a container is running is to shell onto a container with `kubectl exec`

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to describe specific container in a pod.

one way to look at events from a specific container from a pod is to use events api.

try below

```
kubectl get ev |grep <pod-name>|grep <container-name>
```

Comment: Thanks @P Ekambaram. I am getting 'No resources found.' on running 'kubectl get ev'